# Lubuntu Taskbar missing

Tags: lubuntu, taskbar

I have recently installed Lubuntu 14.04 but when I start my computer and logs in the only thing I see is my wallpaper and my trashcan.

Lubuntu worked fine when I tried it before installing but now I cant see the taskbar. If I login as guest the taskbar is there.

I also gets a message that says:

```
Failed to set new theme
Failed to create file '/home/<username>/.cache/xfce4-notifyd-theme.rc.Z095SX': Permission denied
```

The six last letters and numbers in uppercase seems to be different every time.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: see https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/1533us/no_taskbar_showing_on_lubuntu_after_login/

Comment: Can you start the LXPanel manually?

Comment: @Rex How do I start the LXPanel manually?

Comment: @KasiyA If I rightclicks where the taskbar should be there is no option to "add new panel"

Comment: enter `lxpanelctl restart`  in the terminal

Comment: @Rex Pressed `CTRL + ALT + F2` to open terminal, then logged in but entering `lxpanelctl restart` just returned `Can't connect to display: (null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find out how to fix this issue I decided to reinstall Lubuntu.
When I installed Lubuntu for the first time I did that because I messed up Ubuntu. 
For some reason I deleted the `.Xauthority` file and after that I wasn't able to use Ubuntu.

So I installed Lubuntu because I used the computer as a server. But under the installation I choose to install Lubuntu "on top of Ubuntu" so I would keep my documents and files. But that didn't delete the `.Xauthority` file. I think that was the problem. I reinstalled Lubuntu with the option to delete Ubuntu and then install Lubuntu. Now everything works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt + t will give you a terminal.  Once you have terminal enter `sudo synaptic`  You will be asked for your password.  Enter it.  The curser will not move.  Hit enter.  This should start the Synaptic Package Manager.  Search for LXPanel and then mark lxpanel for re-installation.  Hit apply.  Hope that helps.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + T does not open a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and remove the config files by typing:

```
rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel
```

then restart lxpanelctl:

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I too was just testing features but suddenly deleted task bar. By click remove panel

try to add panel and but the panel might be empty

try to add widget by right clicking on it .

click config panel

you might see widget

then add all the widgets and arrrage widgets according to

Your nesssity
Then apply