# Lubuntu 18.04 missing Taskbar

Tags: lubuntu

I followed the suggestion to enter sub synaptic command terminal, and I got this message

```
(synaptic:7435): dbind-WARNING **: 17:00:02.794: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

Not sure what to do in the Synaptic Package Manager....

Comment: What does "sub synaptic command terminal" mean? And what does any of this have to do with the question title?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the first answer here [Lubuntu Taskbar missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576686/lubuntu-taskbar-missing) and got the error message, I think it is due to a missing or unselected component. Please run

`sudo apt-get install at-spi2-core`

and see if the error is gone. Also if you killed the  `lxpanelctl` process restart it with  `lxpanelctl restart` and 
`openbox --restart`.
Restart or login as a guest user to see if the panels show.