# Missing system tray from taskbar lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, system-tray, lxqt

I have asked about the missing system tray over on Ubuntu Forums, but nobody seems interested in the question. It is frustrating because a few programs minimize to the system tray instead of shutting down, and so I don't have an easy way to access them. Anyway the system tray appears and disappears seemingly at random during a session. System reboot doesn't help. I tried the suggested actions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192363/lubuntu-18-04-missing-taskbar) with no luck. So, I'm stuck. Really could use some help with this.

Edit 1: Just to get a baseline, I rebooted and printed out the currently running programs [here](https://justpaste.it/2xh5o) using the following command:

```
top -n 1
```

If there is any more system state information that would be helpful, I will get it up here as I learn about it.

Comment: As a Lubuntu developer, I'm struggling to imagine what could potentially be leading to this toggling behavior, outside of perhaps some element in the system tray mishandling things. Maybe try removing some of your applications that minimize to the tray one at a time?

Comment: I started by disabling user-added programs at startup. Do you think that removing them entirely would bring up different results?

Comment: It's quite possible, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I found that clicking reset in "Configure Panel" would flash the system-tray for a split second then hide it again.  The panel was actually doubled up in the same position.  I moved the overlapping panel to the top edge of the screen and then deleted the panel.  This only happened because I was setup with panels on double monitors and when I unplugged my external monitor it consolidated the panels to one screen which I think is a bug.

Comment: This worked for me. The random 'toggling' was the overlaying bar disappearing and reappearing. Thanks!